# Transforming SVG to CANVAS, PNG, and JPEG with c3.js

Tags: canvas, png, jpeg, c3.js

I'm trying to convert an svg chart to png and jpeg format in order to download the chart. However, I didn't get the same picture. Could somebody tells me why I get a black screen. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

here is the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zdvX.png[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zdvX.png)

Comment: It looks like some CSS is not applied. Probably you have some global stylesheets, which do not get used, when converting.

Comment: How can I fix that ? which markup I've to add ?

Comment: To say something about that, we would need to see some of your current code ...

Comment: <div id="chart"></div>

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using some library like html2canvas http://html2canvas.hertzen.com to convert the C3 SVG to canvas and then to PNG/JPEG

For html2canvas, from http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html

> As a result, it is only able to render correctly properties that it
>   understands, meaning there are many CSS properties which do not work.

Other libraries that use the same method may have similar gaps.

---

### Correcting Black Backgrounds and Thick Lines for C3.js + html2canvas

Assuming you are using html2canvas, the following block of code will correct the black fill and thick axes problems you are seeing

```
// c3 chart generation code
....


// set the properties that html2canvas does not recognize / assumes wrongly in a way that it does / explicitly
d3.selectAll('#chart *').each(function (e) {
    if (d3.select(this).style('fill-opacity') == 0)
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0);
    d3.select(this).style('fill', d3.select(this).style('fill'));
    d3.select(this).style('stroke', d3.select(this).style('stroke'));
});
d3.selectAll('#chart text').each(function (e) {
    d3.select(this).style('font-size', d3.select(this).style('font-size'));
    d3.select(this).style('font-family', d3.select(this).style('font-family'));
});

// html2canvas does not recognize dy
d3.selectAll('#chart tspan').each(function (e) {
    // convert em to px
    if (d3.select(this).attr('dy').indexOf('em') !== -1 && d3.select(this).style('font-size').indexOf('px') !== -1) {
        d3.select(this).attr('dy', d3.select(this).attr('dy').replace('em', '') * d3.select(this).style('font-size').replace('px', ''));
    }

    if (d3.select(this).attr('dy') != 0) {
        d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('y', Number(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('y')) + Number(d3.select(this).attr('dy')));
        d3.select(this).attr('dy', 0);
    }
});



// html2canvas code
....
```

If you are using some other library, you might need to add / remove to the above block depending on the CSS properties it understands.

Comment: can you help me please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779805/how-can-export-a-chart-to-image